# how to change cell height in cocos2d (iphone)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i want to change the height of cell  in cocos2d ..
how to do that tell me please ....

help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
CGSize cSize;

cSize =CGSizeMake(150,35);

vTable  = [[CCTableView tableViewWithDataSource:self size:CGSizeMake(cSize.width, winSize.height-(2*cSize.height))] retain];
```